# Rails: returning the latest data of fields

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I get a hard time what I'm going to return the latest data on my database:

```
              - registration.registration_replies.each do |registration_reply|
                - if registration_reply.present?
                  = registration_reply.confirmation.titleize + "ed"
                - else
                  Not Confirmed
```

and it returns

`Re Assigned Confirmed` on my show page

on my pry:

```
[2] pry(#<#<Class:0xf8585e0>>)> registration.registration_replies
  RegistrationReply Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `registration_replies`.* FROM `registration_replies`  WHERE `registration_replies`.`registration_id` = 45  ORDER BY created_at DESC
=> [#<RegistrationReply id: 28, message: "asdasd", registration_id: 45, owner_id: 2, reply_to_id: 6, cc_id: ["", "4"], created_at: "2014-09-10 09:53:19", updated_at: "2014-09-10 09:53:19", confirmation: "re-assign">,
 #<RegistrationReply id: 27, message: "registration.registration_replies.each do |registr...", registration_id: 45, owner_id: 2, reply_to_id: 6, cc_id: ["", "7"], created_at: "2014-09-10 09:50:11", updated_at: "2014-09-10 09:50:11", confirmation: "confirm">]
```

what I want to show only is the latest registrationReply which id is 28 and `confirmation: "re-assign"`

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for this?

```
= registration.registration_replies.last.confirmation.titleize  + "ed"
```

Comment: NoMethodError - undefined method `last' for #<RegistrationReply:0xe8f7600>:
  activemodel (4.1.5) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:208:in `method_missing'

Answer (score 0):

**I got this!**

I solve this issue by putting scope on my model:

```
scope :latest_status, -> { order('created_at DESC LIMIT 1') }
```

and adding :latest_status on:

```
- registration.registration_replies.latest_status.each do |registration_reply|
```

so everytime the system fetch, the latest registrationreply only will be shown.